# box-sizing + child object

Tags: html, css, parent-child

This has been annoying me a lot today. What I want to do it control the size of a child object using 100% of the parent minus a margin, say 10 px, using the box-sizing method.

I know that it is possible to use the box-sizing function with the parent and 10 px padding and then set the child to 100% but I want to know if if is possible the other way around.

Here's what I have .... at the moment all that happens is that the child box fits itself 100% to the parent object, the margin is not visible.

```
<div id="Parent">
   <div id="Child">
   </div>
</div>
```

And...

```
#Parent
{
height:500px;
width:500px;
background-color:red;
}

#Child
{
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:10px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is a working example and the parent in reality isn't a fixed width?

Comment: In that case, there's really no other effective solution.  You could apply a padding to the parent, but it would have to be defined in pixels, and wouldn't be entirely accurate.

Comment: That's what I'm using at the moment, ah well, at least I can stop worrying about it now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is the only safe way, for now. As an alternative, you can use css3 value expressions like calc(), but not all browsers support it.

http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

You can find some examples on w3c's "CSS3 Values" page http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc0